# How to transfer JSONarray to another JSONarray?

Tags: arrays, json, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a JSONarray of 600 JSONobjects which is immutable, but I would like to simply remove the objects form one index to another. Context - I am handling this in Groovy.

I suppose the easiest way is to create another JSONarray and iterate over the original while inserting new values? Does anyone have a more elegant way of handling this?

Comment: Do you have code that shows what you tried?  What problems did you have? Any error messages?